# YouTube API PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api

Не могу поставить лайк на видео, пишет `Invalid Credentials` в консоле все хорошо, а посылаю через curl — ошибка. Вначале руководства написано отправить POST сюда https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate, а после выполнения запроса в консоле сюда идет POST — https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=N3nR9IFYgbc&rating=like&key={YOUR_API_KEY}. Мои попытки:

- Отправил access_token, id видео, rating=like и ключ сервера сюда https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate - ошибка
- Отправил то же самое без ключа - ошибка
- отправил access_token сюда https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=N3nR9IFYgbc&rating=like&key={YOUR_API_KEY} - ошибка

Что нужно отправить?

Comment: глупый вопрос, но вы YOUR_API_KEY заменяли?

Comment: Ну конечно заменял

Answer (score 1):

Все, разобрался, нужно отправить пустой POST на https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id={ID_VIDEO}&rating={LIKE_OR_DISLIKE_OR_NONE}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}&access_token